# Crear Fixture Con Canchas y Horarios

Tags: php

estoy tratando de generar un fixture (ya tengo el codigo para generarlo) pero no consigo crearlo de la siguiente forma:

Son 19 equipos en total por lo tanto son 18 fechas
El torneo se juega en 3 canchas y en 3 horarios diferentes por lo tanto, deberían jugar sus 18 partidos de la siguiente forma:

- 6 en cancha 1
- 6 en chancha 2
- 6 en cancha 3
- 6 a primer horario
- 6 a segundo horario
- 6 a tercer horario

Es posible esto? El código que tengo es

```
<?php
/* 
 * This code owes an enormous debt to 
 * http://www.barrychessclub.org.uk/berger2001.htm 
 */

function main() {
    ?>
    <style>
    input, textarea { display: block; margin-bottom: 1em; }
    label { font-weight: bold; display: block; }
    </style>
    <h1>Fixtures Generator</h1>
    <p>This page is part of <a
    href="http://bluebones.net/2005/05/league-fixtures-generator/">bluebones.net</a>.</p>
    <?php
    // Find out how many teams we want fixtures for.
    if (! isset($_GET['teams']) && ! isset($_GET['names'])) {
        print get_form(); 
    } else {
        # XXX check for int
        print show_fixtures(isset($_GET['teams']) ?  nums(intval($_GET['teams'])) : explode("\n", trim($_GET['names'])));
    }
}

function nums($n) {
    $ns = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $ns[] = $i;
    }
    return $ns;
}

function show_fixtures($names) { 
    $teams = sizeof($names);

    print "<p>Fixtures for $teams teams.</p>";

    // If odd number of teams add a "ghost".
    $ghost = false;
    if ($teams % 2 == 1) {
        $teams++;
        $ghost = true;
    }

    // Generate the fixtures using the cyclic algorithm.
    $totalRounds = $teams - 1;
    $matchesPerRound = $teams / 2;
    $horacancha = 6;
    $rounds = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRounds; $i++) {
        $rounds[$i] = array();
    }

    for ($round = 0; $round < $totalRounds; $round++) {
        for ($match = 0; $match < $matchesPerRound; $match++) {
            $home = ($round + $match) % ($teams - 1);
            $away = ($teams - 1 - $match + $round) % ($teams - 1);
            // Last team stays in the same place while the others
            // rotate around it.
            if ($match == 0) {
                $away = $teams - 1;
            }
            $rounds[$round][$match] = team_name($home + 1, $names) 
                . " vs " . team_name($away + 1, $names);
        }
    }

    // Interleave so that home and away games are fairly evenly dispersed.
    $interleaved = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRounds; $i++) {
        $interleaved[$i] = array();
    }

    $evn = 0;
    $odd = ($teams / 2);
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($rounds); $i++) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            $interleaved[$i] = $rounds[$evn++];
        } else {
            $interleaved[$i] = $rounds[$odd++];
        }
    }

    $rounds = $interleaved;

    // Last team can't be away for every game so flip them
    // to home on odd rounds.
    for ($round = 0; $round < sizeof($rounds); $round++) {
        if ($round % 2 == 1) {
            $rounds[$round][0] = flip($rounds[$round][0]);
        }
    }

    // Display the fixtures        
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($rounds); $i++) {
        print "<p>Round " . ($i + 1) . "</p>\n";
        foreach ($rounds[$i] as $r) {
            print $r . "<br />"; 
        }
        print "<br />";
    }
    print "<p>Second half is mirror of first half</p>";
    $round_counter = sizeof($rounds) + 1;
    for ($i = sizeof($rounds) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        print "<p>Round " . $round_counter . "</p>\n";
        $round_counter += 1;
        foreach ($rounds[$i] as $r) {
            print flip($r) . "<br />";
        }
        print "<br />";
    }
    print "<br />";

    if ($ghost) {
        print "Matches against team " . $teams . " are byes.";
    }
}

function flip($match) {
    $components = split(' vs ', $match);
    return $components[1] . " vs " . $components[0];
}

function team_name($num, $names) {
    $i = $num - 1;
    if (sizeof($names) > $i && strlen(trim($names[$i])) > 0) {
        return trim($names[$i]);
    } else {
        return $num;
    }
}

function get_form() {
    $s = '';
    $s = '<p>Enter number of teams OR team names</p>' . "\n";
    $s .= '<form action="' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '">' . "\n";
    $s .= '<label for="teams">Number of Teams</label><input type="text" name="teams" />' . "\n";
    $s .= '<input type="submit" value="Generate Fixtures" />' . "\n";
    $s .= '</form>' . "\n";

    $s .= '<form action="' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '">' . "\n";
    $s .= '<div><strong>OR</strong></div>' . "\n";
    $s .= '<label for="names">Names of Teams (one per line)</label>'
        . '<textarea name="names" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>' . "\n";
    $s .= '<input type="submit" value="Generate Fixtures" />' . "\n";
    $s .= "</form>\n";
    return $s;
}

main();

?>
```

Gracias, saludos!

Comment: Y cual seria el problema que tenes?

Comment: Hola, no sé cuál sería la función que tendría que usar o agregar para poder decir qué partido se jugará a primer horario en cancha 1, a segundo, etc...

Comment: A que te referis con la funcion? la armaste?

Comment: Perdon la demora, no armé ninguna función, lo que quiero saber es si hay algo parecido ya hecho o me conviene hacerlo con Excel, o algun otro programa... Estoy perdido..